# Python requests, при выводе всего сайта выводит body и после него: Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 534000470010449392-29143315938413509

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

После вывода soup выводиться :

Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 534000470010449392-29143315938413509

И в конце:Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 534000470010449392-29143315938413509
Поэтому я постоянно не могу компилировать код, то оно качает сайт, то нет. Уже и прокси подлючил, думал , что банят ботов, но ничего не прикратилось

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

http_proxy  = "http://128.199.239.230:8080"

proxyDict = {
              "http"  : http_proxy
            }

url = "https://eldorado.ua/uk/vytjazhka-gunter-hauer-agna-600-gl/p71226038/"
Headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36", "accept": "*/*"}

def get_html(url , params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = Headers, params = params, proxies = proxyDict)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
    items_e = soup.find_all("div", class_="product-head-text")

def parse ():
    html = get_html(url)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```

Comment: На сайте стоит капча, то есть надо доказать что вы человек

Comment: `Incapsula` - это же защита от роботов, с ней надо разбираться